# React Native Test build for testing team

Tags: testing, react-native, build

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am new in mobile application development and react native development.

I have developed a react native application and wants to give the build to be tested to QA team.

How do we give the build?

Should we give just the apk file, which needs to be installed in their phone? Or is there a way to test in unix server where we can mention the test device details.

The QA person should be able to test with different mobiles, right? So I guess there will be a provision to test just like we have the sdb devices to test in dev environment.

Please help me with this, I can't find any solution anywhere.

Again thanks in advance.

Comment: Are [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/app-center-app-react-native) what you need?

Comment: Thanks flix.
This will be helpful for me for sure in a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fabric.beta](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/overview.html) for your purposes. You`ll be able to produce beta builds for all devices and QA you have.

About environment: it should be in your app, some solution for switching target api (dev/prod) or something else.

Comment: Thanks Kirill.

I would like to know how are we able to deploy a react native project in test environment for the QA to test.

I am doing this for a personal project and I am a beginner in mobile app development. So I am unaware how the QA gets to test the developed mobile app.

Please let me know how I can install in unix, so that the qa can test the app.